# Check if a symbolic matrix is hermitian

Tags: matrix, conditional

I have a symbolic matrix:

```
Potential = 
 SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> V0/2, Band[{2, 1}] -> V0/4, 
   Band[{1, 2}] -> V0/4}, {2*max + 1, 2*max + 1 }]
```

with `max = 3` and `V0` to be determined later, but it's a  **real** number.

If I check `HermitianMatrixQ[Potential]`  it returns `False` because it does not know that `Conjugate[V0] = V0`.

How can I set conditions on `V0` to specify it's a real number?

Comment: Check the docs of `HermitianMatrixQ[]`, particularly the `SameTest` option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Simplify[ConjugateTranspose[Potential] == Potential, V0 ∈ Reals]
```

> True