# HermitianMatrixQ Ignores Assuming, $Assumptions

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, complex, assumptions

`HermitianMatrixQ` seems to ignore a variety of ways I tried to help it get the right answer.  For example,

```
mat = Sum[a[i] PauliMatrix[i], {i, 0, 3}];

Assuming[{a[_] \[Element] Reals}, HermitianMatrixQ[mat]] (* False*)

$Assumptions = {a[_] \[Element] Reals};
HermitianMatrixQ[mat] (* False, even though *)
FullSimplify[mat - mat\[ConjugateTranspose]] (* {{0,0},{0,0}} *)
```

So, by the last line, we can see that `mat` really IS hermitian and `FullSimplify` is powerful enough to demonstrate it.  But, `HermitianMatrixQ` is not, presumably because it's not checking for `$Assumptions`.

The advice in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182778/check-if-a-symbolic-matrix-is-hermitian) is to specify a `SameTest`.  However, as you might imagine, this may not be an easily sustainable choice when the matrix has more symbolic parameters.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to get `HermitianMatrixQ` to pay attention to assumptions of any kind?
2. Is this the intended behavior?  Is this a bug?
3. Can one formulate a `hermatianMatrixQ` that is aware of `$Assumptions`, accepts `Assumptions->…`, and knows about `Assuming`?

Comment: Since I'm asking if it's a bug, I observed this behavior in `$Version=="12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"`.

Comment: As a workaround, changing `a[_]` to `Re[a[_]]` as `Array[Re[a[#]] &, 4, 0].Array[PauliMatrix, 4, 0] // HermitianMatrixQ` yields `True`.

Comment: A friend points out this related gem: `Assuming[{a \[Element] Reals}, Conjugate[a]]` yields `Conjugate[a]`.

Comment: Yes it is intended. No it is not a bug. Documentation for `Assuming` states it only affects functions that take `Assumptions` as an option. Those are listed in the Properties & Relations section.

Comment: So why does HermitianMatrixQ not accept assumptions, rather than the relatively unusual SameTest?

Comment: I think this question can be improved by asking for a (nice) way to get around this designed behavior.

Comment: Good idea —- so edited!